# Hosting a MySQL DB on the cloud

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, cloud, hosting

I used to develop app with classical hosting, let's say we have an MVC app running a MySQL database hosted in a classical hosting company like Godaddy

My question is : My application seems very fast, and managing well concurrent connections, but will grow probably exponentially. So I am wondering if keeping my application layers (app files) on Godaddy and moving the database on the cloud like Amazon-RDS is possible. And if possible will it make my app faster than it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defintely possible, but might not be the best solution: it depends on wether or not you are having a latency problem or a database query performance issue. Using aws to host MySQL gives you almost unlimited ability to scale up the performance of your db operations, but if that is not the bottleneck, it won't do you much good. Hosting the web on godaddy and db on aws will introduce additional latency between the web and the db.

Personally, if you are thinking of moving Part of your stack to aws, you might as well move the web layer as well -you'll get fast and scalable db performance with none of the additional latency cause by use both hosts and disparate locations.

Comment: It will definitely cause a bottleneck even with limited traffic.  If cost is a factor move your stack to Digital Ocean or Linode which have  good performance on a single machine with ability to scale starting at $10-$20/month. Amazon and Google are pretty expensive if you are only using the database.

Comment: So I guess if I move the db as well as the web app to Digital Ocean or Linode I still can keep my domain name at Godaddy at least, because I want to keep the domain name actually

Comment: Yes, you can keep your domain anywhere you want. There is no dependency.

Comment: Regarding the domain name, I really recommend hosting the DNS zone on route53, as it's much faster than GoDaddy DNS when making changes. You can still use GoDaddy as the registrar of the domain name, so you can easily renew it when needed. Regarding moving the DB only, I tried this once and the latency was horrible, as E.J Brennan mentioned.

Comment: Couldn't agree more +1 for route53, its great.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to deploy your web application on the same infrastructure where you are going  to use your MySQL database. Amazon RDS provides you a great way where you can scale up or down your MySQL database. As far as I know, the hosting provider that you mention has its own infrastructure, so I would deploy your application on the same Amazon datacenter.

However, you have more options than using AWS, as there are some PaaS (Plarform as a Service) which use Amazon as an IaaS. The benefit of using a PaaS is that you can scale up or down your application in the same way that you are thinking about your MySQL database.